# Check incoming network traffic in real time?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, network-monitoring, network-traffic

Is there a way I can monitor incoming network traffic in real time on my server? Preferably in terms of *bps

Running Ubuntu

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ifstat:

```
rilindo@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ifstat
[sudo] password for rilindo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ifstat
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 23.4kB of archives.
After this operation, 94.2kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/universe ifstat 1.1-8 [23.4kB]
Fetched 23.4kB in 0s (34.6kB/s) 
Selecting previously deselected package ifstat.
(Reading database ... 92838 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking ifstat (from .../ifstat_1.1-8_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up ifstat (1.1-8) ...
rilindo@ubuntu:~$ ifstat
       eth0                br0                virbr0              vnet0               vnet1               vnet2               vnet3               vnet4       
 KB/s in  KB/s out   KB/s in  KB/s out   KB/s in  KB/s out   KB/s in  KB/s out   KB/s in  KB/s out   KB/s in  KB/s out   KB/s in  KB/s out   KB/s in  KB/s out
    4.67      5.21      3.67      5.05      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
    3.93      4.59      0.38      0.74      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
    3.93      4.59      6.19      8.30      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
    3.93      4.59      3.03      4.33      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

Answer (score 15):

Another good one to look into is called [**iftop**](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/iftop/) - which will show connections and bps and has some pretty decent features.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I use iptraf, you can set it to use Bits or Bytes.